# SQL query- help in implementation

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have two tables: *Member* and *Document*

Member table:

```
Memberkey(Key)                    Member country
--------------                    ---------------
111                                   Aus
222                                   US
333                                   Germany
444                                   Chile
```

Document table:

```
Memberkey(notNULL)  doc_type_cd   doc_cat_cd  docname                                          
----------------    -----------   ----------  -------------
111                        1         1          Sales_doc
222                        2         1          Finance_doc
222                        3         3          Legal_doc
333                        3         3          Legal_doc
444                        2         1          Finance doc
444                        3         3          Legal_doc
```

My requirement is to fetch *memberkey*, *member country*, and *doc_name* only if the **document is legal_doc** (i.e. doc_type_cd = 3 and doc_cat_cd =3). If no such document exists for a member, then this should come as *null*.

Output:

```
Memberkey     member country   doc_name
----------    --------------   -----------
111              aus             NULL
222              US              Legal_doc
333              Germany         Legal_doc
444              Chile           Legal_doc
```

How can I achieve this? If I use *condition* on `doc_type_cd` and `doc_cat_cd` in the query, then those members will be skipped, who have no *legal_doc* (111 in this example). Also, if a member has no entry in "document" table, then it should also be shown with member key, country and documentname(NULL in this case). Is there any effcient way to achieve this?
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? I assumed that you use MSSQL in my answer, so that query could not run on other RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

You need a left join for your requirement.  By left joining on the three conditions below you will get a record for every member, and if they do have a legal document than that will be populated in the doc_name column, and if they do not have a legal document than the value will be null.

```
SELECT M.MemberKey,  M.[member country], D.doc_name
FROM Member M
LEFT JOIN Document D ON
M.MemberKey = D.MemberKey AND
D.doc_type_cd = 3 AND
D.doc_cat_cd = 3
```

Comment: Actually, my requirement is a little complex than this. But I have taken care of those but my query has become complex. Here, I provided a gist of where I am stuck. In my case, I cant use left join. Thats is why I am trying to find any logic or function to achieve this.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm confused too Siyual.  I had two downvotes, but that is the correct way to solve this problem.

Comment: First of all, tell us which RDBMS do you use

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a case statement, and test for doc_type_cd or doc_cat_cd, like this:

```
select memberkey,
       [member country], 
       case when doc_type_cd = 3 or doc_cat_cd = 3 then doc_name else null end
from memberTable mt
left outer join documentTable dt
on mt.memberKey = dt.memberKey
```

Comment: With an inner join you would skip any members that dont have any documents

Comment: Fair enough.  Edit made.  Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot! Is there any other way to achieve the same. I mean any logic or function ? I have actually provided a gist of a situation where I am stuck. I am nto sure if I can use case statement, thats why I am asking.

Comment: The only other potential issue Bill Gregg is that you could get multiple member rows for any member that has more than one document (say one legal and one non-legal)

Comment: A case statement is pretty straight forward and easy to use.  It let's you decide what to return on a row by row basis.  Looking at the other columns available in that row of the universal table, decide "oh, in this case I want to return the name, otherwise I want NULL".

Comment: @MDiesel Yes, that is true.

Comment: But only one row should come for a member and only corresponding to legal document. If a member has other documents, then those should not be shown, not even as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in **MSSQL**:

```
SELECT
    M.MemberKey
    , M.MemberCountry
    , DCA.DocName
FROM
    [Member] M
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT
            D.DocName
        FROM
            [Document] D
        WHERE
            D.MemberKey = M.MemberKey
            AND D.doc_type_cd = 3
            AND D.doc_cat_cd =3
    ) DCA
```

Please note, that this query will retrieve multiple rows if there are multiple legal documents. If you want to get the first document, add `TOP(1)` to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which could run on most RDBMS:

```
-- Query to get all members with legal document
SELECT
    M.MemberKey
    , M.MemberCountry
    , D.DocName
FROM
    Member M
    INNER JOIN Document D
        ON M.MemberKey = D.MemberKey
WHERE
    D.doc_type_cd = 3
    AND D.doc_cat_cd =3

UNION ALL

-- Query to get all members without legal document
SELECT
    M.MemberKey
    , M.MemberCountry
    , NULL AS DocName
FROM
    Member M
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Document D WHERE D.MemberKey = M.MemberKey AND D.doc_type_cd = 3 AND D.doc_cat_cd = 3)
```